# Can't connect to router with wlan

Tags: 14.04, wireless, apache2

I am trying to provide access to a apache server over wifi.

Hence I try to connect the ethernet port of my machine to the WAN port of the router so that other machines to get access to it

But the ubuntu fails to connect to the connection

Any help?

Comment: can assigning a static ip solve the problem?

Comment: Is it wan or wlan? It looks like you mean wan. Then it is completely wrong.

Comment: Yes i am sorry i mean WAN

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Try to connect server to lan ;-) If it has dhcp it is better either way.

Comment: as in server <-> router <-> client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WAN and LAN Ethernet ports are on different "sides" of the router.  WAN is usually a dhcp client and LAN has dhcp server.  Plug web server into LAN side and plug client into LAN side then it should work.  In other words all you need is a switch, not a router.

If this is WiFi, there is a security setting that prevents wifi clients from communicating with each other.  Turn this (Virtual Network Segmentation) off.

Comment: OP needs actually and AP.

Comment: woah that fixed everything ....Thank you so much @jnajna and @ Pilot6